# How to solve error while compare the list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put the delete icon if the ID is the same as userID. Now my error is will show 'match' first then show 'not match'. I already get my userID after login, now I want to check my data from API. If the data is posted from my userID then I want to put the delete icon. Now I get the output like this:

```
I/flutter (32208): match
I/flutter (32208): not match
```

So my delete icon cannot appear.

here is my code:

```
final decodedData = json.decode(response.body);
 for (var item in decodedData.data){
  if(item.userId == userID){
   print('match');
   isDelete = true;
  } else if(item.userId != userID){
   print('not match');
   isDelete = false;
 }
```

code for widget:

```
Expanded(
 flex: 1,  
 child: isDelete ? 
   SizedBox(
    height: 22.0,
    width: 22.0,
    child: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 22.0),
      onPressed: () {
     pressDelete();
    },
  )
 ) : SizedBox(height: 22.0,width: 22.0,)
),
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have `5` items the you have to draw `5` Widgets for them. To do that you can use `loop`. Here is an exp

```
class test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _testState createState() => _testState();
}


class _testState extends State<test> {

  final userId=21323123;
  // items 
  List items = [1,2,3,4,5];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
      children: items.map((item){
          // Your Item design
          // Usage Example
          return YOURWIDGETDESIGN(
            child:Expanded(
              flex: 1,  
              child: item.userId==userId ? 
                SizedBox(
                  height: 22.0,
                  width: 22.0,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 22.0),
                    onPressed: () {
                  pressDelete();
                  },
                )
              ) : SizedBox(height: 22.0,width: 22.0,)
              ),
          );

        }).toList(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have problem when is 'match', I want to show delete icon. Now it always show 'not match'. Is I write the code wrong way？

Comment: you say the decodeData contains multiple items, so how can I seperate it to do is match show icon else not show icon.

Comment: @Chin i suggest to create custom widget to handle this, rather than a function

Comment: how many item is based on the user post. some time maybe 2 data is same userId or sometime did not have samr userId

Comment: for create a custom widget, can you give me some example code? sorry, I am new in flutter

Comment: can you please share some code that you have implemented for the icon?

Comment: there are lot of problems there. Suppose for the first post isDelete gets true, then for the next it gets false again.. so your widget will be dependant upon the last item, also you will not be able to show the icon on all widgets

Comment: @Chin check i have given you an example